# Интересная задача js

Tags: javascript

Функция использует деструктурирование для разбора аргументов. Но у нее есть
проблема: вылетает ошибка, когда передается опциональный объект без свойства
enable. Поскольку все параметры имеют значения по умолчанию, хотелось бы чтобы
функция не возвращала ошибку. Существует ли простой способ решить эту проблему?

```
function go(options) {
  let {
    speed = 4,
    enable: {hyperdrive = false,
    frobnifier = true}
  } = options;
  console.log(
    "speed=", speed,
    "hyperdrive:", hyperdrive,
    "frobnifier:", frobnifier
  );
}
go({speed: 5});
```

2) Типичная ошибка в JavaScript. Мы создаем ряд функций в цикле и ссылаемся на
внешнюю переменную из этих функций. Все они будут ссылаться на одну и ту же
переменную, которая в конечном итоге будет увеличена до 10. В данном примере
callbacks [2] не выводит в консоль 2. Выводится 10, как и во всех функциях в массиве.
Какое решение для таких ситуаций в ES5?

```
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  callbacks.push(function() { console.log(i) })
}
callbacks[2]();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Все по аналогии с присвоением дефолтных значений:

```js
function go(options) {
  let {
    speed = 4,
    enable: {
      hyperdrive = false,
      frobnifier = true
    } = {}
  } = options;
  console.log(
    "speed=", speed,
    "hyperdrive:", hyperdrive,
    "frobnifier:", frobnifier
  );
}
go({speed: 5});
```

2) Как вариант, передать в контекст `i`:

```js
var callbacks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function( index ) {
    callbacks.push(function() { console.log(index) })
  })(i);
}
callbacks[2]();
```